# Why does a circle plotted in MATLAB appear as an ellipse?

Tags: matlab, plot, geometry

I wonder in MATLAB how I would plot a circle and show it correctly instead of by default showing it as an ellipse. I guess it has something to do with the local coordinate system in the axis.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the command [`axis equal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) to set the data units to be the same on each axis. Here's an example:

```
theta = linspace(0, 2*pi, 100);
subplot(121);                     % Show the default plot
plot(cos(theta), sin(theta));
title('Default axes settings');
subplot(122);                     % Show a plot with equal data units
plot(cos(theta), sin(theta));
title('Equalized tick spacing');
axis equal;
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

In addition to using `axis equal` as [@gnovice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1861339/plot-circle-but-show-ellipse-in-matlab/1861374#1861374) suggested, you can turn off the stretch-to-fill feature by using [daspect](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/daspect.html):

```
daspect manual
```

or even setting the axes aspect ratios explicitly to:

```
daspect([1 1 1])
```